# Removing substring by length

Tags: c#, substring

I've been trying to remove a substring by a specific length at the beginning or at the end.

Here's the code I've written and not working, though.

```
this.temp = String.Empty;
foreach (string line in this.txtBox.Lines) {
    if (Envir.Operations.Begin == true)
        this.temp += line.Substring(Envir.Operations.Length - 1) + Environment.NewLine;
    else
        this.temp += line.Substring(0, line.Length - Envir.Operations.Length) + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Would you be so kind to let me know if you have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why doesn't it work, what errors do you get?  If it is an index out of range consider checking the length of the line before performing the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good, for except it does not check for input string being longer than you the length you need. It may result in out of range exception. Modify your code like this:

```
    this.temp = String.Empty;
foreach (string line in this.txtBox.Lines) {
    if (line.Length<=Envir.Operations.Length) {
        this.temp += Environment.NewLine;
        continue; // adding new line if input is shorter
    }
    if (Envir.Operations.Begin)
        this.temp += line.Substring(Envir.Operations.Length - 1) + Environment.NewLine;
    else
        this.temp += line.Substring(0, line.Length - Envir.Operations.Length) + Environment.NewLine;
```

}

Comment: other than this think of using StringBuilder and it's AppendLine method instead of multiple +=(string, string)

Answer (score 0):

line.Substring must have two parameters, the start index of substring and the length

Replace with

```
 if (Envir.Operations.Begin)
 {
   this.temp += line.Substring(0, Envir.Operations.Length - 1) + Environment.NewLine;
 }
```

Comment: in this case yes, he has two case intial case when line don't exist and second case

Comment: It gets like this
`foreach (string line in this.txtBox.Lines)
                {
                    if (Envir.Operations.Begin == true)
                        this.temp += line.Substring(Envir.Operations.Length - 1, line.Length - Envir.Operations.Length) + Environment.NewLine;
                    else
                        this.temp += line.Substring(0, line.Length - Envir.Operations.Length) + Environment.NewLine;

                }`

Still not working though.

Comment: @AbnerAlmeida: "not working" is *never* a good enough description of what's going wrong. It's like going to the doctor and saying "I'm not well" and expecting a diagnosis, without letting him examine you.

Comment: All right. Envir.Operations.Begin and Envir.Operations.Length values are reaching this method. It just does not removes the substring.